# how to create different session on url based in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, session, session-cookies, passport.js

Our site have two section :

```
1. admin (content management)  
2. site
```

Admin section will have url '/admin' and site section have url '/'.

Example : My site name is www.example.com, then admin section url is "www.example.com/admin" and site url is "www.example.com".

I want to create url based session means request from admin section will have different session than request from site section.

How can i do it?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using express, you can separate your routers for your routes and apply the session middleware to each router.

**routes/index.js**

```
var express = require('express'),
    router = express.Router(),
    session = require('express-session');

router.use(session({
    secret: 'index route secret',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));

module.exports = router;
```

**routes/admin.js**

```
var express = require('express'),
    router = express.Router(),
    session = require('express-session');

router.use(session({
    secret: 'admin route secret',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));

module.exports = router;
```

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express();

app.use('/', require('./routes/index'));
app.use('/admin', require('./routes/admin'));

app.listen(3000);
```

[documentation](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#router)

Comment: I see it is important the order you add the routers to the app, but I dont understand why? :(  What I am trying to do is to have some routes generating sessions and others fully open with no sessions at all. Depending the order how I add the different routes this works, but I dont understand why.

Comment: @jgato Because the routers are added to a "stack". When a request is made, it loops through the stack to find a match to the route.